# DES — Can I recover the key when I have both ciphertext and the plaintext?

Tags: cryptanalysis, keys, des, known-plaintext-attack

Given a message and DES encrypted form of said message, is it possible to efficiently compute the key used to encrypt the data?

Comment: by efficient do you mean faster than brute force?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Efficiently - no. However, the best attack on DES - [linear cryptanalysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_cryptanalysis) - works with known plaintexts, and theoretically may work slightly faster than the brute force even for small amounts of data.

Computing linear relations between plaintext $P$ and ciphertext $C$, an attacker is able to enumerate all keys according to their likelihood. The [PhD thesis by Junod](http://crypto.junod.info/phdthesis.pdf) provides a comprehensive description of the attack for various parameters in Sections 3.1, 3.2. There is a formula of the probability that the correct key is found among the $r$ candidates with the highest score after analysis of $\nu$ (plaintext,ciphertext) pairs. Given only few ciphertexts, all the keys will have almost the same likelihood, and $r$ must be very close to $2^{56}$ to provide the success rate close to 1. Still, the resulting attack must be faster than the brute force, even though only marginally.

Answer (score 4):

No. This is known as a known-plaintext attack, and AFAIK no such attack is faster than bruteforce for DES.

However, DES only uses a keyspace of $2^{56}$, so you could theoretically still bruteforce it.